# Unable to clear terminal using `Ctrl + L` in guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

So, I am using XUbuntu 18.04 version, inside Oracle Virtual Box 5.2.18. Now,  whenever I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, it gives me a prompt saying it's going to switch to seamless mode, but I want my terminal to clear itself.

Any help? I am using Windows 10 as my host OS.
Please comment if you need any other information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either configure Virtual Box shortcut keys, or use command `clear` in terminal.

**Edit (or elaboration):** The shortcut which I was using to clear the screen was `Right Ctrl + L`, but `Right Ctrl` key is by default the **Host Key** for Virtual Box, that's why it was clearing the screen, in fact, it was giving me some other Virtual Box options. Now if I press `Left Ctrl + L`, I am able to clear the screen.

But if you don't want to use `Left Ctrl` key, you can configure your Host Key and other type of shortcut keys according to your preferences by going to Virtual Box's `File -> Preferences -> Input -> Virtual Machine` option .

I changed my host key to Right Shift which I rarely use for normal shortcuts.